# Clarification on two parts to a question about Sylow and $A_5$

Tags: group-theory

I am tackling this question. I am having difficulty on parts $e$ and $g$. If anyone could help me out that would be appreciated.

I made a post about part $e$ but I don't know if I explained it properly since I seemed to get responses to part $f$ instead which I understand.

My thoughts for $e$:

Really stuck don't have any good ideas to move forward:

My thoughts for $g$:

Well every subgroup of $A_5$ of order $10$ is contained in the normaliser of some Sylow $5$ subgroup and so for one of the six Sylow $5$ subgroups we will get $D_{10} \leq N_{A_5}(P)$ and they are both of order $10$ so we get $D_{10}=N_{A_5}(P)$ for that particular $P$ but I don't know about the other $5$ Sylow $5$ subgroups.

Please help thanks!

[image]

Comment: For the last part since all sylow 5-subgroup of a group are isomorphic so their normalizer would be isomorphic too.

Answer (score 1):

For part (e)

Since $|D|=10=2\cdot5$, by Sylow's Theorem, $D$ has a unique Sylow $5$-subgroup say $P$.
So $P\lhd D$ and hence $D\leq N_G(P)$.
Also, note that $P$ is also a Sylow $5$-subgroup of $G$.